# How to redirect a WP page with this in the url.. ?page_id=xx

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

Trying to redirect a page that is here:

```
http://examplepage.com/?page_id=843&cs_search=1&c_=Carefree&s_=AZ
```

There are several pages with the same page id of 843 that I would like to redirect to the home page.

I've tried a billion different solutions, but just can't quite figure it out.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, and should catch only that single pageid:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([&]|^)page_id=843([^\d]|$)
RewriteRule (.*) /? [R=301,L]
```

- ?page_id=843 `Redirected`
- ?a=b&page_id=843 `Redirected`
- ?a=b&page_id=843&b=c `Redirected`
- ?a=b&aapage_id=843 `NOT Redirected`
- ?page_id=8435 `NOT Redirected`

Comment: Thank you Ben!  You've saved me a TON of frustration and time.